# I write a cralwer in nodejs,it contains 2 http requests in a big loop,i use async but why it will hold a few minutes after send 5 requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, web-crawler

```
async.eachSeries(nameArr, function(val, callback) {
    http.get('http://www.google.com/s?wd=' + val, function(response) {
        var stack = '';
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            stack += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            var $ = cheerio.load(stack);
            var googleUrl = $('#1 .t').find('a').eq(0).attr('href');

            http.get(googleUrl, function(res) {
                collection.update({
                    name: val
                }, {
                    $set: {
                        job_url: res.headers.location
                    }
                }, function(err, result) {
                    callback();
                });
            })
        });
    })
}, function() {
    console.log('done');
})
```

As u can see

nameArr is an array contains about 3000 data.
first step, I request to get an googleurl.
second setp,I use that googleurl to get some data to store in my mongoDB.

but after every 5 request it will hold a few minutes to continue.
how to solve this?
Or is there any better way to achieve my goal?

Plz help!!!